# Generating adjacency matrix on random cout of graphs with output the matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, graph

I've developed program, which may work with graphs and its edges (connections between vertices):

http://ideone.com/FDCtT0

```
/*
   Oleg Orlov, 2012(c), generating randomly adjacency matrix and graph connections
*/
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Graph
{
    internal int id;
    private int value;
    internal Graph[] links;

    public Graph(int inc_id, int inc_value)
    {
        this.id = inc_id;
        this.value = inc_value;
        links = new Graph[Program.random_generator.Next(0, 4)];
    }
}

class Program
{
    private const int graphs_count = 10;
    private static List<Graph> list;
    public static Random random_generator;

    private static void Init()
    {
        random_generator = new Random();
        list = new List<Graph>(graphs_count);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Capacity; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Graph(i, random_generator.Next(100, 255) * i + random_generator.Next(0, 32)));
        }
    }

    private static void InitGraphs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Graph graph = list[i] as Graph;
            graph.links = new Graph[random_generator.Next(1, 4)];

            for (int j = 0; j < graph.links.Length; j++)
            {
                graph.links[j] = list[random_generator.Next(0, 10)];
            }

            list[i] = graph;
        }
    }

    private static bool[,] ParseAdjectiveMatrix()
    {
        bool[,] matrix = new bool[list.Count, list.Count];

        foreach (Graph graph in list)
        {
            int[] links = new int[graph.links.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
            {
                links[i] = graph.links[i].id;
                matrix[graph.id, links[i]] = matrix[links[i], graph.id] = true;
            }
        }

        return matrix;
    }

    private static void PrintMatrix(ref bool[,] matrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} | [ ", i);

            for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0},", Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, j]));
            }

            Console.Write(" ]\r\n");
        }

        Console.Write("{0}", new string(' ', 7));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("---");
        }

        Console.Write("\r\n{0}", new string(' ', 7));

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}  ", i);
        }

        Console.Write("\r\n");
    }

    private static void PrintGraphs()
    {
        foreach (Graph graph in list)
        {
            Console.Write("\r\nGraph id: {0}. It references to the graphs: ", graph.id);

            for (int i = 0; i < graph.links.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", graph.links[i].id);
            }
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Init();
            InitGraphs();
            bool[,] matrix = ParseAdjectiveMatrix();
            PrintMatrix(ref matrix);
            PrintGraphs();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }

        Console.Write("\r\n\r\nPress enter to exit this program...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The example there is using the `const` value, but you could erase `const` and fill `Random int`.

At the ideone as you see the result is ok and are able to see the generated matrix (result):

> ```
> 0 | [  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ]
> 1 | [  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]
> 2 | [  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ]
> 3 | [  1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ]
> 4 | [  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, ]
> 5 | [  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ]
> 6 | [  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ]
> 7 | [  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ]
> 8 | [  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
> 9 | [  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, ]
>        ------------------------------
>        0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
>
> Graph id: 0. It references to the graphs:  8
> Graph id: 1. It references to the graphs:  4 8
> Graph id: 2. It references to the graphs:  4 2 4
> Graph id: 3. It references to the graphs:  1 0 1
> Graph id: 4. It references to the graphs:  7 5
> Graph id: 5. It references to the graphs:  9 7
> Graph id: 6. It references to the graphs:  6 9
> Graph id: 7. It references to the graphs:  3 6
> Graph id: 8. It references to the graphs:  5 2 5
> Graph id: 9. It references to the graphs:  2 0 9
>
> Press enter to exit this program...
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Graph
```

What this class represents is not a whole [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29), it's a single [vertex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29) (or node). Because of that, you should rename this class to either `Vertex` or `Node`.

```
internal int id;
```

You shouldn't have non-private fields, use properties for that. For more information about reasons, read Jon Skeet's article [*Why properties matter*](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).

Also, I don't understand why are you marking fields `internal`, since the whole class is already `internal` (that's the default for top-level classes). You should mark them `public`, so that if you decide to make the class `public` in the future, you don't have to change the fields (or rather properties, see previous point) too.

One more thing: you should also change the name to `Id`, that's the naming convention used for non-private members.

```
class Program
```

All methods of this class are `static`, so you should make the whole class `static`. Although it might also make sense to put all the graph-related code into a separate (non-`static` class). A good name for this new class might be `Graph`.

```
private const int graphs_count = 10;
```

This should be `static readonly`, rather than `const`. `const` fields should be used only for values that you know will never change. This is most important if you're writing a library, but it's a good habit to get used to it everywhere.

```
private static List<Graph> list;
```

`list` is a very unclear name, a better name would be something like `graphs` (or `nodes` after you fix the name of the class `Graph`).

```
public static Random random_generator;
```

Again, the naming convention for non-private members is something like `RandomGenerator`, you should change that. And again, public fields should be changed to public properties.

```
private static void Init()
private static void InitGraphs()
```

Having methods that have to be called before a class can be used is a sign of bad design. You should use constructor for that.

```
Graph graph = list[i] as Graph;
```

There is no need for the `as` here, the type if `list[i]` is already `Graph`.

```
list[i] = graph;
```

This line doesn't do anything, you should remove it. In C#, `class`es are reference types, so if you change members of the local variable `graph` here, `list[i]` will be also changed (because it refers to the same object).

```
private static bool[,] ParseAdjectiveMatrix()
```

This is again a very confusing name. There is no such thing as “adjective matrix”, it's called [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), so you should rename this method. Also, “parsing” usually means reading some string. A better name for this method would then be `CreateAdjacencyMatrix`.

```
int[] links = new int[graph.links.Length];
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason for this array, you could simplify your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.links.Length; i++)
{
    int linkedId = graph.links[i].id;
    matrix[graph.id, linkedId] = matrix[linkedId, graph.id] = true;
}
```

Or even better, use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var linked in graph.links)
{
    matrix[graph.id, linked.id] = matrix[linked.id, graph.id] = true;
}
```

```
private static void PrintMatrix(ref bool[,] matrix)
```

You should get rid of the `ref` here. `ref` is useful if you want to change some variable of the caller (and not just its contents) or in very rare cases when you want to avoid copying a large value type. But `matrix` is an array, which is a reference type, and you don't change it, so the `ref` has no use here.

```
Console.Write(" ]\r\n");
```

You should use `Console.WriteLine(" ]")` here instead. This applies to other places in your code where you use `\r\n` too.